# Redgate profilers equivalent for .Net Sharepoint

Tags: redgate

I was wondering whether there are any recommended open source performance and memory profilers equivalent to Redgate?  This is for .Net and SharePoint development.

Thanks.

Chris.

Comment: We use Red Gate ANTS to profile our .NET/Sharepoint 2007 applications... :) what's driving you away from that?

Answer (score 1):

[Eqatech](http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler) has a free performance profiler, but it only works down to the method level.

[NProf statistical profiler](http://code.google.com/p/nprof/) for .NET applications.

Commercial (not free): [Memprofiler](http://memprofiler.com/) and Redgate's [ANTS profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_memory_profiler/index.htm) are both excellent and worth purchasing. As is JetBrain's [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/).